# ssrs how to make the report available to my local machine

Tags: configuration, ssrs, ssrs-2016, configuration-manager

I have been struggling in [Configuring Report Server URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-report-server-urls-ssrs-configuration-manager) for a certain reporting services server.

when I am in the server itself, the url works fine as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

but trying to access it from my local machine via internet explorer I get the following:

[image]

this has all been set up by a consultant and I am not sure if it is all right.

what do I have to do to make these reports on this particular server available to my users?

or at least, is there a default procedure to start troubleshooting?

Below is the view of my reporting services configuration manager.

the service account
[image]

web server URL
[image]

database
[image]

report manager URL
[image]

[image]

Comment: First, I notice you're using 2016 SSRS, but 2012 Config Manager. You should use the newer Config Manager to match your SSRS version. Also, **the URLs in your first two screenshots aren't the same.** http://Server/Reports_GP  vs http://Server/reportserver

Comment: @AMtwo I have tried every possible way and it does not connect. is there anywhere to have a look at (logs, etc)?

Comment: You can check the SSRS logs (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles), but I suspect that you're never hitting the service, so the logs won't have anything. Have you ruled out firewall/network issues?

Comment: @AMtwo Yeah, that sorted the case out. It was the firewall!! pretty simple. Now I will add a rule for that and it should all be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the URLs referenced in the screenshots aren't the same: `http://server/Reports_GP` vs `http://server/reportserver`. In the comments, you clarified that you've double-checked on URLs, and confirmed that it still isn't working.  On to the next step!

The error indicates that your browser session isn't connecting to the service itself--however, since you're able to run the browser on the server itself and connect successfully, we know the service is listening. If you check the SSRS logs (Depending on your instance root directory, they will be somewhere like: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`), you should be able to confirm that the SSRS service isn't receiving any connection.

This indicates it is likely a networking / firewall / connectivity issue of some type. Is HTTP traffic being allowed through all firewalls (physical & software) between your desktop & the server? Most likely this issue is **not** a problem *with* SSRS, but rather a problem *reaching* SSRS.